# How to substitute environment variable in TeamCity docker compose build?

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0, teamcity-8.0, teamcity-9.1

I am trying Teamcity on-premise solution using docker-compose.
I have a project which needs a docker compose runner type.
Here is the docker compose override yaml file:

```
version: '3'


services:
  
  nextjs:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: ${NEXTJS_DOCKERFILE:-Dockerfile}
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
      - /app/node_modules
      - /app/.next
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

I have added the env variable using parameter on build configuration too:
[image]

The docker compose step gives the following error:

[image]

It seems like the variable substitution is not happening, I am not sure why.
Could anyone tell me what is happening?

Team city version : 2022.04.2

Thanks

Comment: I have a very similar problem, so if you figured this out, please self-answer :)

Comment: Hi @Timo, I have raised it with their support team, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-77117/Environment-variable-not-substituting-while-running-the-build-using-docker-compose-runner